# Por qué cuando inserto una imagen en mi html solo me aparece un icono de imagen pequeña?

Tags: html5, css3, vscode

bueno lo que pasa es que me cambie de disco solido y quería probar haciendo una pequeña pagina web en html, entonces inserte una imagen y solo aparece un icono, lo raro es que yo uso visual studio code y tiene una extension de live server y cuando inicio mi pagina con el live server si se logra ver. No se a que se deba esto, pero me tiene un poco extrañado. ayuda porfavor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MiPágina</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Pagina de prueba</h2>
        <img src="/img/brand.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Esta es una imagen de mis archivos]

Answer (score 2):

En este caso debes utilizar la ruta de la siguiente forma.

```html
<img src="./img/brand.jpg" alt="logo">
```

Comment: gracias, ya se arreglo, que raro el mismo vsc me pone así la ruta de la imagen

Answer (score 1):

#### Problema

El "ícono pequeño" que mencionas, indica que no se ha podido encontrar el recurso, 404 error.

#### Causa

Se debe a que tienes el `index.html` en la raíz del proyecto, pero las imágenes están dentro de una carpeta.

#### Solución

Subir de nivel la ruta `../img/brand.png`